# Bootstrap or CSS Grid? - 3 columns of equal height but content overflowing

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

My aim is to create a container which has three columns with the content inside. I'm not sure how to do so with bootstrap, or whether CSS Grid is the correct way of doing so.

I don't want to create three columns but have one column/section divide into 3 by their total height similar to the picture below, so that *the sections will overflow from one column to another*.

The columns would be in the order : 1,2,3 from left to right horizontally and : 1,2,3 from top to bottom vertically.

[image: A single row with 3 columns of div's inside it]

Comment: So, first of all, will this be responsive? Also, will the order of these elements change depending on the screen size? Or it would be something like 1, 2, 2 continued, 3, 3 continued, 4 ?

Comment: yes, responsive and will reorder on a small screen to one column with the order of 1 onwards from top to bottom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without resorting to JS, what you are describing must be done with CSS columns.

```css
.columns {
  columns: 3 auto;
  padding: 10px;
}

.columns,
.item {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.item {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.item1 {
  background-color: #B8B4AD;
}

.item2 {
  background-color: #D9DFE5;
}

.item3 {
  background-color: #FFB83E;
}

.item4 {
  background-color: #E86807;
}
```

```html
<div class="columns">
  <div class="item item1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean eu est et nunc placerat tempus. Quisque mollis orci et purus mollis scelerisque. Nunc non facilisis enim. Mauris tincidunt dui sed tristique tempor. Phasellus consectetur lorem ut felis maximus efficitur. Donec tortor sem, aliquam a libero at, rutrum auctor ligula. Cras id viverra turpis. Aenean malesuada, metus id fringilla vehicula, sem nibh ullamcorper sapien, sit amet sollicitudin massa nisi id mauris. Fusce aliquet pretium dui, a mollis est vehicula id. Phasellus pulvinar suscipit ex, non venenatis magna laoreet rutrum. Curabitur sollicitudin, leo et gravida dapibus, ex ante luctus nunc, a posuere ligula augue ac arcu. Proin a magna at neque blandit feugiat eget a massa. Donec id euismod enim, quis iaculis diam. Integer pellentesque facilisis magna, et ultricies turpis. Ut aliquet eros quis risus blandit posuere. Quisque tincidunt orci vel ipsum rhoncus eleifend. Curabitur vel est eu elit bibendum tincidunt. </div>
  <div class="item item2">Nulla posuere, mi et ultrices volutpat, arcu mi feugiat velit, et semper urna justo sit amet est. Aenean ac felis eu ligula ultrices ullamcorper eu ut quam. Cras dignissim condimentum ante, nec convallis tortor. Vestibulum ante est, convallis quis dui id, convallis viverra felis.</div>
  <div class="item item3">Donec ut justo sapien. Curabitur iaculis dolor et felis congue, ac ornare nunc dignissim. Duis egestas erat at sem molestie gravida. Quisque hendrerit erat vel magna condimentum mollis. Vestibulum faucibus iaculis enim eget commodo. Donec cursus dolor sed tincidunt semper. Pellentesque pellentesque lobortis ante a elementum. Nunc tellus libero, egestas et dui eu, consectetur consequat enim. Etiam malesuada sagittis eros eu consectetur. Aenean faucibus, massa quis pulvinar vulputate, nisi ex mollis lorem, id fringilla eros elit non est. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Nulla ornare, libero vel consectetur venenatis, enim leo pretium purus, ut commodo nibh sapien eu neque.</div>
  <div class="item item4">Vestibulum mi ligula, auctor at suscipit sed, dapibus in purus. Sed ut semper ligula. Integer tincidunt nisl id turpis eleifend sagittis. Phasellus pretium, justo sed finibus eleifend, eros nulla interdum libero, quis feugiat tortor est eu erat. Ut volutpat, ligula a dapibus dignissim, sapien diam molestie arcu, quis vulputate enim lorem lobortis nisl. </div>
</div>
```

You could only achieve something like the following with CSS Grid:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(8, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 10px;
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 10px;
}

.grid,
.item {
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.item1 {
  grid-row: 1 /3;
  grid-column: 1;
}

.item2 {
  grid-row: 3/9;
  grid-column: 1;
}

.item3 {
  grid-row: 1/5;
  grid-column: 2;
}

.item4 {
  grid-row: 5/9;
  grid-column: 2;
}

.item5 {
  grid-row: 1/4;
  grid-column: 3;
}

.item6 {
  grid-row: 4/9;
  grid-column: 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="item item1">1</div>
  <div class="item item2">2</div>
  <div class="item item3">3</div>
  <div class="item item4">4</div>
  <div class="item item5">5</div>
  <div class="item item6">6</div>
</div>
```

Content would not *flow* across a grid columns.

Comment: "Must be done" with CSS columns - is strong language, and I disagree.... I believe that you could also do this with [grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) - better would be to say _could be done_ with columns.

Comment: how would I achieve this with grid? and thank you for that answer, is this also responsive e.g. on a small screen I would like it to shrink to one column and be in order downwards (1...n)?

Comment: Check the 2nd snippet for an approach using grid. The columns approach can easily be made responsive by starting at `columns: 1` then changing it to `columns: 3` at the desired breakpoint.